# RedirectToAction won't works, it runs but do not route to the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Thank You!!

I have a question.

The RedirectToAction won't work, it runs but do not route to the url

it runs the edit controller first

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        CheckAccess();

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }  

         .....
    }
```

it will access to the CheckAccess() method, when it runs the 
return RedirectToAction("Error", "Index"); it runs ok but not route to the url, and then back to the "Edit" controller and run the next command "if (id==null).

```
    public ActionResult CheckAccess()
    {
        int StaffUserType = 5;
        if (Session["StaffUserType"] != null)
            StaffUserType = Convert.ToInt32(Session["StaffUserType"]);

        if (StaffUserType == 5)
        {

            //return Json(Url.Action("Index", "Error"));
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Index");
            //return View("ErrorController/Index");

        }
        else
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { id = StaffUserType });` is the proper usage. The action name should be mentioned as first argument, then controller name.

Comment: And what is the point of your `if (id == null)` - you have already exited and will never reach that line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Edit() would never return the RedirectToAction Result, because the return values from CheckAccess() isn't captured and returned.

You could modify CheckAccess() to return a bool

```
public bool CheckAccess()
{
    int StaffUserType = 5;
    if (Session["StaffUserType"] != null)
        StaffUserType = Convert.ToInt32(Session["StaffUserType"]);

    if (StaffUserType == 5)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then check for this result in Edit, and return RedirectToAction if the result was false.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (!CheckAccess())
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }

    .....
}
```